# How to deploy two rails app in linode.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linode

Somehow i managed to run two rails apps in my linode hosting, but i am not sure what i doing is correct or wrong ..?

I created virtual host for subdomain, navigated to that subdomain directory and started rails server.

Now again navigated to another directory which have another rails app and started rails server again.

So currently i have two rails running in my remote.

[image]

Is this right way of running two rails server in remote..? Sorry for being naive :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do that. rails -s is only for local development, not for serving on your production site. Instead your simplest option is something like Passenger (mod_rails) - this is free and open source. So:

```
gem install passenger

sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

and follow the instructions.

Also, have a look at this linode article about how best to deploy rails:

http://library.linode.com/frameworks/ruby-on-rails-apache/ubuntu-10.04-lucid

Answer (score 1):

try this for deploying rail application

https://gist.github.com/1031946

for rails 3.1

http://www.iamseree.com/application-development/how-to-set-up-rails-3-1-applications-on-linode